# A While Loop Thread

Tags: c#, while-loop

So I've been trying to create a bit of code that sends data on a while loop, specifically an alive packet to a server through a UdpClient.

```
 static void doSend(string ip, int port)
    {
        while (isSending)
        {
            _sockMain = new UdpClient(ip, port);
            // Code for datagram here, took it out
            _sockMain.Send(arr_bData, arr_bData.Length);
        }
    }
```

But when I call the "Stop" method, it gets stuck in a constant loop and doesn't come out. How can I put the while loop into a Thread? So I can abort the thread on stop, cancelling the loop?

Comment: If you never change the variable `isSending`, you will never go out from you loop

Comment: Yes, when I press a button isSending = false
But it just doesn't exit.

Comment: Then the problem could be not in your loop, but somewhere in the code for datagram.

Comment: you need to post more code, this isn't enough

Comment: Maybe it is, AmazingDreams...
And, I'm sorry Alan...

Comment: It seems that you have a problem with your `isSending` variable's scope. Post more code (like where you are declaring `isSending`). And just try to debug the value of your variable after clicking the button

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It hangs because your doSend method works on UI thread. You can use something like the below class to make it run on a seperate thread or you can use [BackgroundWorkerClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
public class DataSender
    {
        public DataSender(string ip, int port)
        {
            IP = ip;
            Port = port;
        }

        private string IP;
        private int Port;
        System.Threading.Thread sender;
        private bool issending = false;

        public void StartSending()
        {
            if (issending)
            {
                // it is already started sending. throw an exception or do something.
            }
            issending = true;
            sender = new System.Threading.Thread(SendData);
            sender.IsBackground = true;
            sender.Start();
        }

        public void StopSending()
        {
            issending = false;
            if (sender.Join(200) == false)
            {
                sender.Abort();
            }
            sender = null;
        }

        private void SendData()
        {
            System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient _sockMain = new System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient(IP, Port);
            while (issending)
            {
                // Define and assign arr_bData somewhere in class
                _sockMain.Send(arr_bData, arr_bData.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I like this! Thank you Taner!

Comment: It's awful! [volatile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile) is not mentioned in any answer.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov that might be because the volatile keyword was added years later !

Answer (score 4):

You can use the backgroundworker thread http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker
and inside dowork() put your while loop. 
You can stop the code by using CancelAsync() and set `backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true`

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
          if (bw.IsBusy != true)
          {
              bw.RunWorkerAsync();

          }

          private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
          {
              // Run your while loop here and return result.
              result = // your time consuming function (while loop)
          }

          // when you click on some cancel button  
           bw.CancelAsync();
```

Comment: This won't work in this way. You need to set the `WorkerSupportsCancellation` and you have to check the `CancellationPending` within your loop. A complete example can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
static bool _isSending;

static void doSend(string ip, int port)
{
    _isSending = true;

    while (_isSending)
    {
        _sockMain = new UdpClient(ip, port);
        // ...
        _sockMain.Send(arr_bData, arr_bData.Length);
    }
}

static void Stop()
{
    // set flag for exiting loop here
    _isSending = false;    
}
```

Also consider to name your methods in PascalCase, i.e. `DoSend` (even `StartSending` will be better), `StopSending`.

Comment: Thank you for this, but it hangs? The program receiving still get's data.

Comment: Because you do sending in a loop. After current sending completes, next one will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `BREAK` statement?

Comment: Please check the links http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd(v=vs.71).aspx, http://www.dotnetperls.com/while. Break statement can be used to terminate while loop.

Comment: I only want to exit it when a button is clicked, otherwise it must keep going?

Comment: Then define a button click event which changes a boolean variable; isSending.